# Making a dynamic table for wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to make a dynamic table. I tried using row definitions. I have an xml table I want to put values from to the dynamic table.

Here's my code:

```
 Grid g = new Grid();

 XElement resultElements = XElement.Parse(e.Result);
 ListBox listBox2 = sender as ListBox;

 // g.RowDefinitions.Add(rr);
 int di = -1;
 foreach (XElement nod in resultElements.Elements(@"studentPunishmentsTable"))
 {
      di++;
      RowDefinition rr = new RowDefinition();
      TextBlock u = new TextBlock();
      penalty = nod.Element("penalty").Value;
      u.Text = penalty;
      g.RowDefinitions.Add(rr);
      Grid.SetRow(u,di);
      g.Children.Add(u); 
 }
```

How can make a dynamic table to read data line by line from a webservice table into a table on a wp7 page?

Comment: What's the questions? Just telling us what you want to do and showing a snippet of code doesn't make it easy to help. See http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: And the error you getting is?

Comment: my Q is how can make a dynamic table to read data line by line from webservice table to a table in wp7 page ?

Comment: uhm, you want it with the WCF and windows phone code or just the WCF side? dude... come on - you need to read a tutorial.

Comment: i want it with wp7 code i've read the tutorial but didnt find thing to help with this even the samples dose'nt work with me

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (XElement nod in resultElements.Elements(@"studentPunishmentsTable"))
 {
              listb.Items.Add(penalty+Environment.NewLine+ issueDate + semesterDesc);
                Grid.SetColumn(listb, colum);
                Grid.SetRow(listb, row); row = row + 1;
}
```

this code make a llist dynamicly ..